# Laravel 5.7 get current logged in user with user profile on one-one relationship

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-passport

I am currently learning `Laravel 5.7`. I have downloaded the source code from [github](https://github.com/sadhakbj/Laravel-vue-spa-vuex). In that code i have implemented one to one relationship with user and profile table.

I have been able to successfully login the user, and able to register the user. However, when i call to method `getCurrentUser()` it only returns the data from only the user table, not from the profile.

**`User Model`**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
   {
     $this->middleware('auth:api')->only('logout');
   }
   public function getCurrentUser(): User
   {
     return request()->user();
   }
    public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
   {
    $credentials = $this->validate($request, [
        'email'    => 'required|email|exists:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:5',
    ]);

    if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = auth()->user();
        /** @var User $user */
        $user['token'] = $this->generateTokenForUser($user);

        return response()->json($user);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['success' => 'false', 'message' => 'Authentication failed'], 401);
    }
 }

}
```

`User`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Encrypt the password while savinf it.
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute(string $password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
    }

}
```

`User Profile`

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    //
        /**
     * The following fields are mass assignable.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 
    'middle_name', 'date_of_birth', 'nationality','phone','image','permanent_address_country',
    'permanent_address_state','permanent_address_district','temp_address_district','temp_address_state','gender','user_id'];

    public function UserProfile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

How can i return the current logged in user and profile details through `Auth` `getCurrentUser` api?

I am using `Vue.js` on my client side.

Comment: You can get the currently authenticated use by doing `$user = Auth::user();` utilising the Auth facade - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Comment: @AndyHolmes i am able to get the current user but not the `user profile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `User` model, change the `User()` method to this:

```
public function userProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
}
```

And in your `UserProfile` model, change the `UserProfile()` method to this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then you could get your user with its profile with this query:

```
User::with('userProfile')->find(Auth::id());
```

In your case, you can refactor the `getCurrentUser()` method to this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function getCurrentUser(Request $request): User
{
    return $request->user()->load('userProfile');
}
```

Comment: how should i return from the `getCurrentUser()`?

Comment: `return request()->user()->load('userProfile');`

Comment: The third code block helped me! 

I was having trouble returning a single user with `return new UserResource($user)`... (resource collections had no issue).

Solved it with: `$user = User::with('userable')->find($request->user()->id);` 

Thanks brother @piscator!